# Insert to a table with PK that is auto-increment

Tags: sql

I have a table named `Books`.
Its columns are `indexNum`, `Bookname`, `Bookedition`,
where `indexNum` is the primary key and is auto-incremented.

I've tried to insert data to the table, however the insert command is rejected.
I tried the following statements:

```
INSERT INTO Books VALUES ('', Birds, a12)
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (NULL, Birds, a12)
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (Bookname, Bookedition)( Birds, a12)
```

The first two statements do not work. The last statement worked the first time, however,  the next time it says that the PK is duplicated.

How shall I insert many rows correctly?

Comment: Is there also a constraint on `Bookname` and `Bookedition`? What do you mean by "how shall I insert many rows correctly"? And how on earth did you insert `Birds` and `a12` without apostrophes?

Comment: Please show your table definition for clarification

Comment: also, add a tag to indicate which database server you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off. I would recommend using a column list. Take a look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) on the correct syntax. Make sure that strings are encased in single quotes.

```
INSERT INTO Books (Bookname, Bookedition) VALUES ('Birds', 'a12')
```

Comment: hey, it doesn't work. it says that one of the columns is missing (the pk column) it doesn't add it automaticly

Comment: Specifying the column names is also good preventative medicine against relying on the order of the columns.  If you don't specify column names, and the underlying table's column order has changed, your code will break.  With column names specified, you're safe.

Comment: error is:  Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' 0.000 sec

Comment: @ronnjack That sounds like it's not incrementing. Make sure that the primary key column is in fact `AUTO INCREMENT`. You can increment it manually using `ALTER TABLE Books AUTO_INCREMENT = 2`

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Books (BookName, BookEdition) 
VALUES ('Birds' , 'a12')
```

--EDIT

Sounds like your missing your Identity column.  If you can alter your table, look into doing that.

If not, try something like this which uses `MAX` and `IFNULL` (for MySQL) or `ISNULL` (for SQL Server):

```
INSERT INTO Books (IndexNum, BookName, BookEdition) 
SELECT IFNULL(Max(indexNum),0) + 1 as NewIndexNum, 'Birds', 'a12' 
FROM Books
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51289/1).

Comment: it gives error 1062. Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: I would guess you don't have an identity/auto_increment field set up in your table -- look into your table structure and alter if needed.

Comment: @ronnjack -- please see edits above -- if you cannot alter your Books table, when Inserting, you Max and IFNULL (for MySQL).  Good luck.